# upgraded 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded from 14.04 lts to 16.04.1, while I did the power went, is there anything I can do to make sure that I did everything right

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will install any pending update needed. If you do not encounter any problem, then you are fine!